# Why am I getting an error while running the second code

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

I am using Google Bigquery to query data from a Public dataset new_york_citibike. I want to get num_bikes available and the average number of bikes available at a station_id. The query is:

```sql
SELECT station_id, num_bikes_available (SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) AS average_bikes_available
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
)
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
```

The second query is:

```sql
SELECT station_id, num_bikes_available, AVG(num_bikes_available) AS average_bikes_available
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
GROUP BY station_id
```

The error which I got is "**SELECT list expression references column num_bikes_available which is neither grouped not aggregated**".
**Why is it so that I have to aggregate the num_bikes_available in the second case.**

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide sample data but I think this is what you are trying to do :

```
SELECT station_id
       , sum(num_bikes_available) as num_bikes_available
       , avg(num_bikes_available) AS average_bikes_available
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
GROUP BY station_id
```

Comment: Yup exactly, but why didn't I had to do in the first example.

Comment: @aryanbarnwal because in your first query you are using a separate query (as subquery) to calculate the average. also that way , you are showing avg() of overal data in your table , not the avg per station

Comment: Ok understood. Thanks for the explanation.